# Malware/Adware on site deployed on AWS Elasticbeanstalk

Tags: amazon-web-services, malware

I guess the title says it all.

I noticed some ads were popping up on a client's site we are currently developing. It only shows on this particular site. Not any other site. It is very annoying to put it mildly.

I thought removing it would be as easy as setting up a new environment on ElasticBeanstalk for it. I was wrong!

I have started a fresh instance for the application, scanned the project folder for malware before deploying, emptied the content of s3 bucket for static files. All these made no difference. The adware/malware is still there.

It has been driving me nuts for the past few days. Does anyone know how to resolve this kind of problem?

Comment: It's not coming from AWS. You are most likely including some malicious JavaScript code on your pages. You might have to use process of elimination to determine what you are including that is causing the issue.

Comment: Thanks Mark B. Your suggestion pointed me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

Mark B pointed me in the right direction.

I used inspect element to check the network processes of pages showing the Malware/Adware. It was after this i noticed a few asynchronous posts going to http://api.adsrun.net/post. Of course, i'm not making any post calls to this link. So i decided to inspect my JavaScript files as seen in View Page Source. Fortunately, it was in the last few lines of the second file i inspected. Immediately i deleted this file, normalcy returned to my web application.

It has been a very frustrating several hours. Thanks once again, Mark B for your suggestion.